# Mapper does not emit anything

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, tesseract, hadoop2

I have a mapreduce job which takes a sequence file which I constructed before. The sequence file has an image file name as the key and the byte representaton of the image as the value. My mapper is supposed to take each image and then process them using an image-to-text library called [Tess4J](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/) which is based on [Tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/). The mapper runs and does not throw any exception but surprisingly the output folder is empty and no file in generated. Here is my mapper code:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.ByteWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

 public class testM extends Mapper<Text, BytesWritable, Text, Text> {

  public void map(Text ikey, BytesWritable ivalue, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    //Read Current Image from File.
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(ivalue.getBytes()));
    Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();           

    try {
        String text = instance.doOCR(img);          
        context.write(new Text("fff"), new Text("fff"));    

    } catch (TesseractException e) {

        context.write(new Text("fff"), new Text("fff"));            
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //String result = instance.doOCR(img);  

}
}
```

and here is the driver code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Image2Text");
    job.setJarByClass(driver.class);
    job.setMapperClass(testM.class);

    // TODO: specify a reducer
    job.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);

    // TODO: specify output types
    //job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    //job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    //input format
    job.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);

    // TODO: specify input and output DIRECTORIES (not files)
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path("inSeq"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("out"));

    if (!job.waitForCompletion(true))
        return;
}
```

I try to output "fff" just to make sure the mapper works, but as I said it does not output anything. If I remove line `String text = instance.doOCR(img);` everything works fine. I examine the content of my sequence file and looked at the value of `img` and both look fine. Does anyone know what the problme can be?

Comment: tesseract needs native libaries, do you have them installed on your slave nodes? I don't see you shipping it as part of the job's resource.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut I added them to my project, isn't that enough? How can I ship them as part of my job?

Comment: Shoudn't I get an error message if it causes the problem?

Comment: Just to let you know my Hadoop cluster is a single node that I run on my own computer.

Comment: You should add `@Override` annotation to your map function in the first place, this is usually the reason why it doesn't execute.

Comment: The mapper does get executed because as I mentioned in my post if I remove line ``String text = instance.doOCR(img);`` it does output.

Comment: Did you test if tesseract is working at all on your computer? If yes, does tesseract produce a not empty output for the image? Are you sure that you would notice the e.printStackTrace(); if executed? Why do you output "fff" in catch clause?

Comment: Yes I tested the Tesseract and it works on my computer and does not produce an empty output. I output "fff" just to make sure the program outputs something but it doesn't.